# $.when.apply not evaluating any of defined functions in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get  $.when.apply to evaluate any of the defined functions in array, what am I doing wrong here?

```
function Logic(address) {
    this.address = address;
}

Logic.prototype.Get = function (pk, success, failure) {
    var scope = this;

    return $.ajax({
        url: scope.address + '/Get',
        type: "GET",
        data: { 'pk': pk },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.hasOwnProperty("d") ? data.d : data);
        },
        failure: function (ex) {
            failure(ex);
        }
    });
};

function Screen(options) {
var scope = this;

if (options.pullings != null)
    {
        $.each(options.pullings , function (i, pulling)
        {
            scope.pullings.push(function () {

                return pulling.logic.Get($('[name="' + pulling.pkField + '"]').val(),
                function (row) {
                    $('#' + pulling.displayControlID).val(row[pulling.displayField]);
                }, null);
            });
        });
    }
}

Screen.prototype.Fill = function (pk) {
    var scope = this;

    $.when.apply($, scope.pullings).then(function () {
      // none of the functions ever gets called and just enters this block
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) takes [Promises](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) or plain values. The function objects you pass in are considered to be values. Why did you expect them to be invoked automatically? You have to do that manually:

```
$.when.apply($, $.map(scope.pullings, function(fn) {
    // calls every function
    return fn();
})).then(function() {
    // this block gets called when all results are available
});
```

Comment: I thought it will recognize I passed an array of functions and my assumptions was it would know what to do with them. This works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax error, change:

```
Screen.prototype.Fill = function (pk) {
    var scope = this;

    $.when.apply($, scope.pullings).then(function () {
      // none of the functions ever gets called and just enters this block
    }
}
```

to:

```
Screen.prototype.Fill = function (pk) {
    var scope = this;

    $.when.apply($, scope.pullings).then(function () {
      // none of the functions ever gets called and just enters this block
    });
}
```

That's my initial thinking, have you checked the console to see what errors you might be getting?

Comment: I copied it wrong, there is no syntax error. I checked console, I had another ajax call inside then block an I could clearly see it being called.

Answer (score 0):

An overlooked alternative to `$.when.apply` is to accumulate `when` promises in the loop e.g. using the pattern `promise = $.when(promise, anotherpromise)`

e.g. something like

```
    // Start with a resolved promise - which undefined represents!
    var promise;
    $.each(options.pullings, function (i, pulling) {
        promise = $.when(promise, Get($('[name="' + pulling.pkField + '"]').val(),
               function (row) {
                    $('#' + pulling.displayControlID).val(row[pulling.displayField]);
               }, null);
    });

    promise.then(function(){
        // called when all promises are completed
    });
```